# dispaly scroll bar in uiwebview without any tap

Tags: iphone

Friends,
i want to display scroll bar(visible) without any tap in uiwebview, when  the size of data  accede to the  uiwebview . i searched a lot but didn't find any solution.

Comment: You want the scrollbar to appear or the ability to scroll? the ability to scroll is already present. If data in a div container is not scrollable then you should check out http://cubiq.org/iscroll

Answer (score 0):

You could place the uiWebView on a UIScrollView.. there you have the option to use fixed scrollbars..